# .delegate works, .live doesn't. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates, click, live

Can someone explain this? My code works properly, now that i use .delegerate but i have no idea why I have to use it.
I have a ajax created element with a class of "ajaxDiv". When I use .live like this I don't get an alert. All the code I wrote after this function won't work either.

```
$(".ajaxDiv").live("click", function(event){
    alert('I don\'t work.')
});
```

But when I do it like this, it work's.

```
$("body").delegate(".ajaxDiv", "click", function(){
    alert('I work like a charm!')
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using jQuery 1.9? [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed.

At the meantime, you can use the [Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) to restore `.live()` or continue using `.delegate()`.

However, for best forward compatibility, consider using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Simply switch the first 2 arguments of `.delegate()`

Answer (score 0):

Live has been deprecated in jQuery.

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
Reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: It being depreciated wouldn't make it stop working, however it being removed would.

Comment: That is correct. TwiNight provided the full answer. However, whatever gets marked as depricated, should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`.live` was removed in jQuery 1.9.  `.delegate` has not been removed yet.  In fact, it is not deprecated, but its use has been superseded by `.on` ([`.delegate` documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  I would suggest that you use `.on` for all bindings including event delegation.